# Bootstrap datepicker not working correctly with ng-blur angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker. I have two dates in same form.

There are two questions/issues.

1. I have use ng-blur to get a date when selected and what to do some operations in angular js controller. I dont want to use ng-change. I want to perform some operation when complete date is selected.

I have created directive for datepicker,

```
directive('myDatepicker', function (gettextCatalog) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        'restrict' : 'A',
        'require' : 'ngModel',
        'link' : function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                'format' : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                'language' : gettextCatalog.currentLanguage,
                'autoclose' : true,
                'clearBtn' : false,
                'todayBtn' : 'linked',
                'todayHighlight' : true
            }).on('show', function (e) {
                element.datepicker('update', ctrl.$viewValue);
            }).on('changeDate',
                    function (e) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(moment(e.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));                        
                    console.log("in directive = " + moment(e.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                }).on(
                'changeMonth',
                function (e) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(moment(e.date)
                            .format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                }
            ).on(
                'changeYear',
                function (e) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(moment(e.date)
                            .format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                }
            );
        }
    };
});
```

Controller look like,

```
angular.module('my.controllers')
.controller('dateOprnController', function($scope) {
    $scope.doOperationOnToDate = function() {
        console.log("in controller = " + $scope.toDate);
    };
});
```

My date picker looks like

```
<div class="right-inner-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    <input type="text" id="fromDate" class="form-control  datepicker" ng-model="fromDate" ng-blur="doOperationStartDate()" my-datepicker>
</div>
<div class="right-inner-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    <input type="text" id="toDate" class="form-control  datepicker" ng-model="toDate" ng-blur="doOperationOnToDate()" my-datepicker>
</div>
```

Consider toDate, If I select toDate, it shows following output in console.

> // I select date = 2015-09-08
>
> in controller = undefined
>
> in directive = 2015-09-08
>
> // I select date = 2015-09-09
>
> in controller = 2015-09-08
>
> in directive = 2015-09-09

In controller it gives previously selected date but in directive gives correct date.

**How can I get correct date in controller when selected?**

2. **How I can disable dates in toDate before date selected in fromDate?**

Comment: This link might help you , if you work it around in opposite way https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3188 
This is for your second point.

Comment: I am not really too expert in angular . but i am confused about the events you have put into directives as I am working on same to and from datepicker and I am able to achieve ng-blur .but stuck in updating the datepicker value of 'to' when 'from' calendar date changes.